# Error: "Unable to find git in your PATH" only in terminal vs code and android studio

Tags: flutter, git

I have added

> "C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program
> Files\Git\cmd;C:\tools\dart-sdk;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\src\flutter\bin;C:\tools\dart-sdk\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;"

in my environtment variables path. That's succesfull when i run flutter doctor in my powershell, but if i run in powershell in vscode, that error occured. The effect is i can't make a new flutter project in vs code and also in android studio.

[i can run flutter doctor in my windows powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wtMi.png)
[i can't run flutter doctor in my vscode powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f1vx.png)

run flutter doctor and make a new flutter project in vscode and android studio

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, in the powershelgl, you're running on the `C` drive and in VSCode, it's running on the `F` drive where flutter is not installed.. This is probably causing the issue.

Hope you find this helpfull.